# Application of Green's theorem for $f(x,y) = (-y, x)$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

> Let $\partial D$ be the boundary for a $C^1$ curve. Show that the area of $D$ is $$\frac12 \int_{\partial D} (x \ dy-y \ dx) = \int_{\partial D}x \ dy = -\int_{\partial D}y \ dx$$

I'm trying to apply Green's theorem to $f(x,y)=(-y, x)$ here and getting $$\frac12 \int_{\partial D} (x \ dy - y\ dx) = \frac12 \int_{\partial D} \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x} -\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial y} \ dx \ dy = \frac{1}{2}\int_{\partial D} 2 \ dx \ dy$$

but not sure how to continue from here. How do I get the limits for the integral?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question to me seems like it's asking you to verify, using Green's theorem, the result you have in your question.

Greens theorem states an alternative way to calculate a line integral $\int_C F \cdot ds$.

If, for example, we are in two dimension, $C$ is a simple closed curve, and $F(x,y)$ is defined everywhere inside $C$, we can use Green's theorem to convert the line integral into to double integral via
\begin{align*}
  \iint_D \left(\frac{\partial F_2}{\partial x} -
    \frac{\partial F_1}{\partial y}\right) dA  
\end{align*}

Pick a vector field  ${\bf F(x,y)}=(−y/2,x/2)$ and verify that
$$\frac{\partial F_2}{\partial x} -
    \frac{\partial F_1}{\partial y} = 1$$
Now, if  $C$ is a counterclockwise oriented simple closed curve that bounds a region where you can apply Green's theorem, the area of the region $D$ bounded by $C=\partial D$ is

\begin{align*}
  \text{Area of $D$} = \int_C F \cdot ds = \frac{1}{2} \int_C x\,dy - y\,dx,
\end{align*}